# How to connect to websocket in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, websocket

I am trying to create a connection to web socket with a link ws://link.net:8888/ws?token= to open communication with the server.

I found out that I could use Stream but I don't know how to add access_token to the end.

```
    Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: host, port: port, inputStream: &inputStream, outputStream: &outputStream)

    if inputStream != nil && outputStream != nil {

        // Set delegate
        inputStream!.delegate = self
        outputStream!.delegate = self

        // Schedule
        inputStream!.schedule(in: .main, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
        outputStream!.schedule(in: .main, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
        print("Start open()")

        // Open!
        inputStream!.open()
        outputStream!.open()
    }
```

And for some reason even if I try to connect to link without access key, I am unsuccessful. So does anyone have a way how to open connection to the socket with access_key added I would be very grateful?

I also tried https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket but it also doesn't have an option to add anything on end, the only thing I will try now it is https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift.

EDIT1:
So after a comment from Dan Karbayev I checked out Starscream with code

```
let url = "ws://link.net:5000/ws?token=token"
let socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: url)!)
socket.onConnect = {
    print("websocket is connected")
}
//websocketDidDisconnect
socket.onDisconnect = { (error: Error?) in
    print("websocket is disconnected: \ 
(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
//websocketDidReceiveMessage
socket.onText = { (text: String) in
    print("got some text: \(text)")
}
//websocketDidReceiveData
socket.onData = { (data: Data) in
     print("got some data: \(data.count)")
}
//you could do onPong as well.
socket.connect()
```

But for some odd reason none of socket methods don't wake up.

EDIT 2:

At the end I ended using https://github.com/tidwall/SwiftWebSocket.
It worked right away.

But thanks to all for help.

Comment: Have a look at this too https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket

Comment: you want to just add token to connection address? where is error or something?

Comment: @Lu_ Yes I am trying to add token to connection address, but even without that I get an error when using Stream: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1.)

Comment: mayby it is about overall connection, do you have App Transfer Security in plist?

Comment: @Lu_ yes I have Allow Arbitrary Loads set to yes.

Comment: Socket.io uses https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream for websockets

Comment: using this test  websoket https://websocket.org/echo.html 
check if websocket connected or not , If connected  add here log please

Comment: @a.masri I know that socket works because I have a test page for that. I don't know what was the problem when I was using other frameworks, but when I used SwiftWebSocket it worked without any problems. But thanks all for help.

Comment: @schmru ok good luck , please add this Answer :)

Comment: https://github.com/tidwall/SwiftWebSocket has no updated version in cocoapods